# How to: Google marker url open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, url, marker

I want to make my map marker opening the map in the new tab. Dou you have any advices?

```
var map = $that.data('googleMap');

                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
function() {
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            });
                        } else if(params.url) {
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
function() {
                                document.location = params.url;
                            });
                        }
```

In footer.tpl I have this:

```
$("#mapContact").addMarker({
      coords: [49.004674, 14.770050],
      icon: '/themes/organie4/img/dorado/contact/location-pin.png',
      url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Husova+75,+Třeboň+I,+379+01+Třeboň/'
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With something like this :

```
var map = ... // Map declaration

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 49.004674, lng: 14.770050},
    map: map,
    icon: '/themes/organie4/img/dorado/contact/location-pin.png',
    url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Husova+75,+Třeboň+I,+379+01+Třeboň/'
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Some text"
});

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    if (this.url) {
        document.location = this.url;
        // Or like this if you want a new tab : window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    } else {
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }       
});
```

I hope this will help you.

**Edit** :
**1)**

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
} else if(params.url) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        document.location = params.url;
    });
}
```

Is replace by :

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    if (this.url) {
        document.location = this.url;
        // Or like this if you want a new tab : window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    } else {
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }       
});
```

**2)**

```
$("#mapContact").addMarker({
    coords: [49.004674, 14.770050],
    icon: '/themes/organie4/img/dorado/contact/location-pin.png',
    url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Husova+75,+Třeboň+I,+379+01+Třeboň/'
});
```

Is equivalent of (but with a "marker" variable) :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 49.004674, lng: 14.770050},
    map: map,
    icon: '/themes/organie4/img/dorado/contact/location-pin.png',
    url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Husova+75,+Třeboň+I,+379+01+Třeboň/'
});
```

**3)**

I don't know what is that :

```
var map = $that.data('googleMap');
```

Here's an example of map declaration :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 49.004674, lng: 14.770050},
    zoom: 7
});
```

**4)**

I don't know where is your "infowindow" declaration but here's a simple example :

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Some text"
});
```

Comment: I don't know where to add this code and if I need to delete older one.

Comment: Thank you for edit. I change that codes but now map is gone.

Comment: Sure. I add an answer.

Comment: Why don't put all Google Maps' JavaScript code in the same file ? Why use a ".tpl" file instead ".js" ? I'v tested my code and it works well, but all is in the same JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Here it is.

**jquery.googlemap.js**

```
var map = $that.data('googleMap');

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
    if (this.url) {
           window.open(this.url, '_blank')
          // Or like this if you want a new tab : window.open(this.url, '_blank');
                   } else {
                                infowindow.open(map, this);
                            }       
                        });
```

**footer.tpl**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: 49.004674, lng: 14.770050},
        map: map,
        icon: '/themes/organie4/img/dorado/contact/location-pin.png',
        url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Husova+75,+Třeboň+I,+379+01+Třeboň/'
  });
```

When I change **footer.tpl** my page "Contact" throw *500 (Internal Server Error)*